# how to retrieve the vector element for the current thread? chat room server

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, chatroom

im creating a chat room server using multithreads and vectors. every new users gives their nickname and i stored the nicknames in a vector. but i don't know how to retrieve the vector element for the current thread. this method bellow is in the thread

```
userName = input.nextLine(); // the user enters their name

usersList.add(userName);     //add it to the vector of users

String word = usersList.elementAt(????);  //how do i retrieve this current username? 

output.println( word + " has joined the conversation.");
```

Comment: let me get this right: you have a multithreaded chat server. each connection gets a thread (or a runnable), and you have a shared user list (an `ArrayList` perhaps?). Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Internal synchrozation of Vector is not enough for your task, I suggest the following

```
Vector<String> userList = new Vector<String>();

synchronized void addUser(String userName) {
    userList.add(userName);
    String word = userList.elementAt(userList.size() - 1); 
    System.out.println( word + " has joined the conversation.");    
}
```

Now you can replace Vector with ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to synchronize the entire method you might encounter deadlock in this way :
For the method invocation of methodA1 Class A obtains a lock on its object and then decides to call  methodB2() on class B object and tries to obtain a lock on ClassB. But if 
there is a method invocation methodB1() in progress in the object of ClassB the effort of ClassA to obtain B's lock and similarly of ClassB to obtain ClassA's lock will be unsuccessful and it will result in a deadlock.

```
 class ClassA {
    public synchronized void methodA1(ClassB classB) {
        classB.methodB2();
    }
    public synchronized void methodA2() {   }
}   

class ClassB {
    public synchronized void methodB1(ClassA classA) {
        classA.methodA2();
    }
    public synchronized void methodB2() {   }
}
```

I would suggest you to use a private final Lock object which will save you from encountering deadlock between cooperating objects.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
void addUser(String userName) {
     synchronized(lock){
        // method body. Add user to list
    } // lock is released. now any cooperating object can use 'lock'. 

   // addUser can obtain a lock on any cooperating object.
}
```